# Connecting input text boxes on one website to the input text boxes on another website?

Tags: javascript, php, jquery, html

There is a website that I would like to pull data from, based on my user's search. The submit button and all inputs would be on my website and the results would be pulled from the website with the data, and have the results shown back on my website, for the user to see. The website that I would like to pull the data from has identical inputs.

Is it possible to connect input text boxes on one website to the input text boxes on another website and have the data requested appear back on my webpage?

Does anybody have any suggestions for doing this? Any ideas? I've never tried anything like this before, so if nothing else, it will be a good learning lesson.

Comment: Not directly. I would make a request to the data website from your website's server rather than handling it all client-side, as cross-origin restrictions might make it difficult.

Comment: yeah, but do you own both sites, otherwise you may have some cors issues depending which site your trying to put data into

Comment: @gcampbell, do you think a web-scrapper/crawler is best of this? If so, I'm not thoroughly familiar with WS/C tools, but I've heard of beautifulsoup.

Comment: @johnny5 I don't own both sites. Just the one.

Comment: Which one the one your sending data too? If so you can just scrape the data you need

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You'll need a data scraper. PHP has Simple HTML DOM Parser: http://simplehtmldom.sourceforge.net/

Or you can use cURL: http://www.jacobward.co.uk/web-scraping-with-php-curl-part-1/

Comment: Thanks for the advice and links! Much appreciated!!

Answer (score 1):

unless you have control over the server of the website you want to fetch data from, no you cannot.

or you can build yourself a HTML **scraper** .